# Sentences with two subject markers

Tags: grammar, particle, subject-particle

For example, the sentence:

> 내가 애기가 있어요.

has two subject markers (`가`).

What are rules or situations to know about when two subject markers are used and why?

Comment: related: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/i-do-not-understand-the-need-of-two-subject-particles-in-사람의-이름이-생각이-안-나요/2540 ; https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/two-subjects-in-당신은-이름이-뭐예요/2473